# C# Emgu FindTransformECC NaN encountered

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to test FindTransformECC function in emgu C#. It is based on this article: [a link](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/)

My code is:

```
    public static Mat AlignImage(Mat sourceimage, Mat template, int iterations, double eps, MotionType _motionType = MotionType.Euclidean)
    {
        float[,,] warp_matrix_temp = new float[2, 3, 1];
        float[,] warp_matrix = new float[2, 3];

        CvInvoke.CvtColor(sourceimage, sourceimage, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(template, template, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);

        Image<Gray, float> wm = new Image<Gray, float>(new Size(2, 3));
        wm.Data = warp_matrix_temp;

        CvInvoke.FindTransformECC(template, sourceimage, wm, _motionType, new MCvTermCriteria(iterations, eps));

        warp_matrix_temp = wm.Data;

        return new Mat();
    }
```

The function is not finished because the FindTransformECC return the error: "Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: NaN encountered.'"
I did not found suitable solution. The input images are ok. I wrote it to file to make it sure.
I am using the Emgu.CV 3.4.1.2976 installed from nuget package.
Could anybody help me please? I do not know what should be the issue.
Thank you very much.

Lucie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EMGU devs found the answer (we discussed in issues in the repo [here](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/120)).
It is need to init the values in the warp array:

```
float[,,] warp_matrix_temp = new float[2, 3, 1] { { { 1 }, { 0 }, { 0 } }, { { 0 }, { 1 }, { 0 } } };
```

This will helps to function run correctly.
I hope this will help somebody else in future.

Lucie